# how to sending mail from an account in rails application with out given Password Credential?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail

I am implementing one of my client requirement..i.e., 
  sending mail from an account in application with out given Password Credential 
i am also surprised after  saw this method one of the website i.e.,

```
        https://www.freshsales.io/
```

i am sending mail through this web ...but all sending mail updated in my gmail sent item...
i have trying in this way by setting up in config file

```
     config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 9292}
      config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
      ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      address:        'imap.gmail.com'or'imap.hotmail.com'or'imap.yahoo.com', # default: localhost
     port:           '993',                  # default: 25
     user_name:      'debasish.industrify2016@gmail.com',
        password:       'deb@industrify',
       authentication: :plain                 # :plain, :login or :cram_md5
      }
```

any one tell me what kind of method or protocol they are using?

Answer (score 0):

The website is not providing the mail service.
In your example, you specified the `debasish.industrify2016@gmail.com` as your mail delivery service account, I believe you use gmail for mail service, then the configuration file in the `config/production.rb` should have something like:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com", # or imap.gmail.com
  port: 587,
  domain: "gmail.com", 
  authentication: "plain",
  user_name: "user_name", # without @domain
  password: ENV.fetch("SMTP_PASSWORD"),
  authentication: :plain
}
```

The password and user_name should not gave away directly, instead, it should be set in your application as *ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES*, I think this might be something you were asking for.

How to set the *ENV* is depends on your production server:

e.g. Heroke:

`heroku config:set SMTP_PASSWORD=deb@industrify`

As for the mail protocol, I only used the `stmp`, you can, of course, use `imap` or `pop3`, [the difference](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=whatis_pop3imapsmtp)

Comment: you told me to give password of my email  but dont want to give any email passward....like that website( https://www.freshsales.io/ )...

Comment: I assume you want to build your own mail server, well, then it's much more complex, sorry, I never did that, so I am sure i am not in the position to answer this, [the reasons why its complex](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/why-you-may-not-want-to-run-your-own-mail-server). This server may or may not have to link to the rails application website. @user6394357